# Reactjs with JSX: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in react. When I render elements with `createElement`, it works fine. But rendering like below with JSX, it throws and error saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

```js
const { createElement } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM; 

const style = {
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    color: 'White',
    backgroundColor: 'Red',
    padding: '10px',
    border: '10px solid black'
}

render(
    <h1 id="emp-title" className="header" style={style}>Full time Employee</h1>,
    document.getElementById('react-container-jsx')
);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <title>React 101</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="react-container-jsx"></div>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Attempts: tried but did not work

```
<script src="index.js" type = "text/babel"></script>
```

Also

```
<script src="index.js" type = "text/jsx"></script>
```

Didn't work. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to link [`babel-standalone`](https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js) as well

And add `type="text/babel"` to the script tag.

Working snippet:

```js
const { createElement } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM; 

const style = {
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    color: 'White',
    backgroundColor: 'Red',
    padding: '10px',
    border: '10px solid black'
}

render(
    <h1 id="emp-title" className="header" style={style}>Full time Employee</h1>,
    document.getElementById('react-container-jsx')
);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
        <title>React 101</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="react-container-jsx"></div>
        <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried Just now. But still does not work. Can you share a working snippet.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kentcdodds/5274dfa1eb31e6d22b9eddd1efc773dc
check out this gist

Comment: Thanks for the link. Along with the babel js, I also had to add the type="text/babel" in order to make it work.

Comment: Yeah `type="text/babel"` is needed, I thought you already know that as you mentioned it in your question.